# how to fix info window in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, web, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display infowindow in google map, but  it showing last marker info not all marker

```
    let myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856 );
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: myLatlng,
      scrollwheel: true,  

      }; 
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra BeachManly Beach Manly Beach Manly Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"),
      mapOptions
    );


    var count;
    var marker=[];
    for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[count][0]
      });
    }


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"<div></div>"
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });

    marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: i think inside the loop  u have to push ur data to marker array. when the loop is running u r just assigning the value to ur array removing the last one that is why only the last one is showing

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your code like this:

```
 var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra BeachManly Beach Manly Beach Manly Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
 ];
var count;
var marker=[];
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {  


let myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]);

let mapOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  scrollwheel: true,  
};

let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("map"),
  mapOptions
  );
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: locations[count][0]
  });
   }

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"<div></div>"
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here I found some issue what you are doing:**

- You are initializing map every iteration in the loop, but it should not. That's why only one marker (last one) is showing.
- You are trying to bind event only one marker (last one) after the loop but it should be for individual marker inside loop.

**I have the following suggestions for to be working:**

- Initialize the map once before drawing marker on map
- Bind marker click inside loop for each marker.
- Set info-window position by the object of latLng

**Here is the working demo:**

```
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra BeachManly Beach Manly Beach Manly Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var count, marker;

// Init map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
    scrollwheel: true,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

// Create info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 350,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10,-25)
});

var infoFn = function (count) {
    return function (e) {
        var content = '<div>' +
            '<span>Location: ' + locations[count][0] + '</span>' +
            '<span>, Lat: ' + locations[count][1] + '</span>' +
            '<span>, Long: ' + locations[count][2] + '</span>' +
            '</div>';

        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map);
        infowindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]));
    }
};

// Add markers
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[count][0]
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    let fn = infoFn(count);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', fn);
}
```

Comment: bro now i need to display location names in that info window......for each marker

Comment: @Pavan, then you have to set the content like: **infowindow.setContent(`<div>${locations[count][0]}</div>`);**. Also I have updated the answer. Please check it now.

Comment: bro not working correctly , am using VueJS...beginner

Comment: @Pavan, prepare info window content before binding click event on marker. See last update.

Comment: @Pavan, Accept this answer if it helps you. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)